# How to format currency in the webshop of Odoo 8?

Tags: javascript, currency, odoo-8, price, variants

We have a webshop on Odoo 8. We are in Canada. So, we like the prices displayed in the format xxx,xx $ (with a comma, not a dot).

Actually, the prices are well formatted in the shop. Except for these cases :

- On a product page, as soon as a product as variants, his price is displayed with a dot, not a comma;
- In the cart, all the prices have a comma until we click on - or + (subtract or add a product). At this moment, the dot comes back.

So, our conclusion is that as soon as the javascript/jquery is used, the price is not well formatted.

Somebody would have a link or a patch to fix the javascript/jquery in the Odoo 8 website_sale module?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with this two posts from odoo.com.

https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/how-to-override-the-price-to-str-function-of-website-sale-js-111804

and

https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/how-to-respect-the-currency-format-in-the-shop-even-with-products-who-have-variants-110439